# Set the fix column width in gridview and if content is bigger than the column width than break the word

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been using Gridview to display data.i set the width of each column using Itemstyle but the Problem is that if the content of that column is bigger than the column width then it will automatically increase column width but i want to break the word if content is bigger than column width...plz help me....

Comment: What does `Wrap="true"` for the ItemStyle do for you ?

Comment: what do you mean with break?Not take the rest that doesn't fit or make two lines in that cell?

Comment: i mean 2 say if content size is bigger than Column size than the content should be break and start with another line....i will show you example...if one column name is OfficeName and we set its width 60px and then   --OfficeName----------------------------------------------------------Loakjdjkjdj----60px is completed---then-----------------------------asgfhffsdhf----means it break from Loakjdjkjdj and  remaing character "asgfhffsdhf" is in second line...thats its meaning...

Comment: Well, that is bad. you don't have any whitespaces in your data.

Comment: its not like that i just put ---- only there is no whitespace..........

Comment: i want just break the sentence if its text size is greater than the column size...so,it will be fix the column size..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Well after investigation it turns out that instead of `span` if we use `div` and add 'word-wrap:break-word' attribute to style it does the trick. Here is the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/UYAb7/

PS:- But please note that `word-wrap:break-word` might not be supported by all browsers and version. If this poses a problem, I suggest you write a function that takes in a `href` and link text and create a link with first few chacters + ... and set complete word as tooltip using `title` property of `anchor` element:

```
public static string CreateLink(string url, string text){
    var linkText=text.Length>10?text.SubString(0,10) + "...":text;
    return string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" title=\"{1}\">{2}</a>", 
                         url,text,linkText);
}
```

<strike>you can added inner content inside a `span` element and set its `max-width` property to the width of the column.</strike>

Example:

```
<Column>
    <ItemStyle Width="100" />
    <span style="max-width:100px;">
       <a href="http://google.com">Google It</a>
    </span>
</Column>
```

Comment: will you please show rendered `HTML` (View Source from browser) for a cell in this column.

Comment: its too much long so i cant paste here...due to limited character Restriction here........

Comment: Just one cell. Grid will be rendered as Table so get one `<td>....</td>` from the column causing problem. Also paste in question. It has enough chars.

Comment: <td style="width:60px;">
                <span style="max-width:60px;">
                    <span id="ucOfficeList_gvList_ctl02_lblCountry">jhjhgdajgfjgjfgjagfjgjahgfjhagahfkjhakhakfhkhag</span>

                    </span>
                </td><td style="width:120px;">
                    <span style="max-width:120px;">
                
                    <a id="ucOfficeList_gvList_ctl02_hyOffice">jhgfjhagjhfgjhagfjgajhgfjhaggjagfafafg</a>
                    </span>
                </td>

Comment: thnxs for trick that given above............ using div its done my work.........thnk u very much..........

Comment: glad I was of any help to you.

Comment: If this has solved your problem you can mark this as an answer by clicking on green arrow under voting buttons. This helps other to find working solutions to their problems easily.

Answer (score 0):

CSS style "overflow-wrap:break-word;" will force a break, even with no whitespace in the cell content, so something like this should work:

```
    <style>
        .bigcols td {
            max-width:410px;
            overflow-wrap:break-word;
        }
    </style>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="bigcols" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    ....
```

Should do the trick.