# Grid View Size changes with size of data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working around this to get a solution,

```
>  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"
> BorderWidth="1"
>                     HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#5c7990" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
>                     AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="false"
>                     EmptyDataText="No records found" CssClass="GridView123" Width="90%" 
>                     OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
>                     <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" />
>                     <FooterStyle CssClass="GridFooter" />
>                     <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" VerticalAlign="Top" Wrap="true" />
>                     <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternateRowStyle" VerticalAlign="Top" Wrap="true" />
>                     <Columns>
>                         <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
>                             <ItemStyle Width="20%"></ItemStyle>
>                         </asp:BoundField>                        
>                         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="100%" ItemStyle-Wrap="true">
>                             <ItemTemplate>
>                                 <span id="PName<%# Eval("ID") %>">
>                                     <%# Eval("Name") %></span>
>                             </ItemTemplate>
>                             <ItemStyle Wrap="True" Width="100%"></ItemStyle>
>                         </asp:TemplateField>
> 
> </columns> 
<asp:GridView>
```

This is my grid view. my problem is the gridview width is changing with diffent data. when the columns have huge data it is expanding and when columns are filled with small data it is shrinking.

I have applied wrapping thing to columns too

I want to have a grid view which will be consistently displayed in unique size what ever the data is filled.

Thanks for all your help...

Comment: Please check this URL. this will help you.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789765/set-the-fix-column-width-in-gridview-and-if-content-is-bigger-than-the-column-wi

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using % width - use a fixed width instead. It may take some trial and error to determine the maximum required width. Set your width in CSS instead and apply a class to the column.

Take a look at this:

http://www.emadmokhtar.com/2012/07/add-elegant-style-to-asp-net-webforms-gridview-controls/

Ideally, if you want clean markup you should be using a ListView which does not emit tables.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width on `<asp:GridView ...` from `Width="90%"` to `Width="640"` and this make it 640 pixel standard width.

To force text to warp and not grow you also need to have not to set the `ItemStyle-Wrap` to true, and ether not have it, ether have it as false.

`ItemStyle-Wrap="false"`

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of redundant width attributes.  You don't need to declare it in the BoundField and ItemStyle for the same column.  However, the reason I believe you are encountering issues is because you are setting up a with of 120%.

What I have found in my countless hours of working with HTML is when using percent widths on table columns, don't exceed 100% and ALWAYS leave 1 column with no width. Even if you add up all the columns to 100% width, I have seen tables do odd stuff.  I usually define widths on all but the "main" column and let that take the remaining amount of width.